# "Please fill the required field" - Hidden field is blocking my submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, blogs

I have a wordpress page with buddyboss installed. The Pagebuilder is Elementor pro. The Plugin Buddyboss gives you Facebook like functions. In buddy boss, it's no problem to comment on posts &co, but if I have a post outside of the buddyboss system, I can't submit my comment. There's one hidden field that must be filled in order to submit my comment. [Line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DV50.jpg)

If I put in a script that targets the area by its Id and tries to delete it, it won't work. If I delete it manually, I can submit it.
Do you guys have any idea?

Without the CSS that hides my Textarea it looks like this:

```html
<textarea 
  id="aad669143d1a2b175fb447cb79a28f4b" 
  aria-label="hp-comment" 
  aria-hidden="true" 
  name="comment" 
  autocomplete="new-password" 
  style="" 
  tabindex="-1" 
  class="error" 
  aria-describedby="aad669143d1a2b175fb447cb79a28f4b-error" 
  aria-invalid="true">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Please supply the code you use trying to delete the textarea. Anyway, it looks as if the id is auto-generated by random, so targeting the textarea by id might not be possible. Have you tried it using another attribute (like `aria-label` e.g.)?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what the question is here? What makes you think that by just removing the form field that you can submit the form?

Comment: @ahuemmer, thank you! 
my code is 
<script> var element_to_remove = document.getElementById('a55d9a4d6a6e26714685e22e656137fb'); element_to_remove.parentNode.removeChild(bad); </script> 

How can I target the aria-label?

Comment: @HowardE The form field is usually hidden through css and is required in order to submit the form. But because its hidden, I can't fill it and so can't submit it. So: removing - no hidden field that blocks my submit.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use jQuery and target the field by name?

Comment: Check the body class to see that buddy boss pages have a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you posted in your comment, it turns out that targeting the `aria-label` might indeed be what you needed. In order to remove it, you would modify your code as follows:

```js
var element_to_remove = document.querySelector('[aria-label="hp-comment"]');
element_to_remove.remove();
```

The first line finds the element based on the attribute `aria-label` and its value `hp-comment`, the second line removes it from the HTML tree (which should work in all modern browsers; alternatively, you could try the `parentNode` way you outlined).

You can try it using this extended code snippet:

```js
var element_to_remove = document.querySelector('[aria-label="hp-comment"]');
console.log(element_to_remove.id); // the id is logged
element_to_remove.remove(); // remove the element
element_to_remove = document.querySelector('[aria-label="hp-comment"]'); // nothing here
console.log(element_to_remove); // --> null is logged
```

```html
<textarea id="aad669143d1a2b175fb447cb79a28f4b" aria-label="hp-comment" aria-hidden="true" name="comment" autocomplete="new-password" style="" tabindex="-1" class="error" aria-describedby="aad669143d1a2b175fb447cb79a28f4b-error" aria-invalid="true">
</textarea>
```

(Of course, the lines 2, 4 and 5 are just for demonstrating and not really necessary.)